# MySQL INSERT with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called notif where I store notifications with timestamp and topic_id. I have another table topic which store topic name. Now I have the topic name and notif content given and I want to insert them into notif table. So I have to select the topic_id from topic based on name and to insert that along with notif text and current time into notif table.

Can this be done in one query?

```
public function insert($text, $name) {
$query = "INSERT INTO notif(content, topic, timestamp) 
          SELECT $text, topic_id, NOW() FROM topic WHERE name = $name"
}
```

Comment: show us what you've got so far and what is/isn't working.

Comment: This is what I have so far and I don't get exception but nothing is written to database

Comment: unsure your db/dbengine, but you may need to commit() before it will show up in the db

Comment: This is just part of code, I do stmp->execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Insert Into notif (topic_ID, NotifText,theTimestampe) (Select topic_ID,NotifText,GetDate() from topic Where name = @param)
```

FYI, untested.

Comment: Drop the parentheses around the `SELECT`

Comment: Parenthesis are optional, at least in SQL Server. I prefer them because they help make the query more readable in my opinion.